# Gaseous States and Laws

Tags: gas-phase-chemistry

What are the factors on which the value of the Boyle temperature depends? And if the Boyle temperature depends on the pressure, then why?

As at the Boyle temperature a real gas becomes ideal, it should be independent of pressure, but on reading an article on internet it confuses me so *please* help me understand why.

Comment: The energy of an ideal gas is independent of pressure, but what do *you* mean by "it should be independent of pressure".

Answer (score 1):

The Boyle temperature only depends on the form of the interaction between a pair of gas atoms. It is not dependent on the pressure.

It is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle_temperature) as the temperature at which the second virial coefficient $B_2(T)$ becomes zero. Near that temperature, over a wide range of pressures, it is true that the equation of state of the gas is quite close to the ideal gas equation, because typically the higher virial coefficients give a relatively small contribution. However, it is not quite right to say that the gas "becomes" an ideal gas. The behaviour is really a consequence of two cancelling contributions, at that particular temperature.

You can see a formula for the dependence of $B_2$ on both the temperature and the pair potential [here](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Second_virial_coefficient). So, if you know the pair potential, and can do the integral (numerically, perhaps) you can calculate $B_2(T)$ for any temperature. If you plot it as a function of $T$, almost always it will go through zero somewhere: this defines the Boyle temperature.

The reason that there is a temperature at which $B_2$ becomes zero, for most gases, is that at very high temperatures $B_2$ is positive, being determined by the repulsive interactions between atoms (which reflect the fact that atoms have a nonzero size), while at low temperatures the attractive forces play the largest part in determining $B_2$, and these make it negative. So somewhere in between, it must go through zero. If you look on [this page](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Second_virial_coefficient) at the section on the (approximate) van der Waals equation of state, you can see these two contributions to $B_2$: $b$ (atomic size) and $-a/RT$ (attractive forces). So in this case, the Boyle temperature, where $B_2$ is zero, is $T_\text{B}=a/(bR)$.